# Retrieve ID python

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I'm trying to retrieve the current ID from a postgresql database using openERP. This is my function (inside a class):

```
def get_id(self, cr):
        cr.execute("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        id = cr.fetchone()[0]
        return id
```

Then, I am calling the function this way:

```
'last_id':fields.function(get_id, method = True, string = 'ID Number', type = 'integer')
```

But I'm getting following error:

> TypeError: get_id() takes exactly 2 arguments (7 given)

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
def get_id(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
     res = {}
     for field in fields:
         cr.execute("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
         id = cr.fetchone()[0]
         res[ids[0]][field] = id
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined function syntax correctly.

```
def get_id (self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
        res = {} 
        cr.execute("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        id = cr.fetchone()[0]
        res[ids[0]] = id
        return res
```

Do some thing like this

please read this doc. https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I've tried what you told me, although now I'm receiving this error: "Keyerror: 2".
I've looked at the link you gave me, I tried a few things but without success.
My code is the same of the first post, but with your changes in the function.

Comment: Actually, your code works, it was my mistake. However, it does not what I really want, because I wasn't perfectly clear of what I wanted.

Whenever I start the form to create a new user, I want to only <b>display</b> (not to write) the current ID of that new user. I thought of getting the last ID then sum +1.

With your code, whenever I try to create a new user the field starts at 0, only when I click the button "create" is when it shows the ID.

Also, I don't want to create another column (last_id), I want to use the current column (ID). How can I achieve this? Maybe only in XML?

Thanks!